# Thymeleaf conditional img src

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to show the user avatar if it exists and show a default avatar if not. The code I use is:

```
<img src="/images/commentavatar1.png" th:src="${comment.user.image} != null ? ${comment.user.image} : '/images/default-user.png'" th:alt="${comment.user.nameSurname}"/>
```

What I see is only the alt tag. The rendered element has an empty src attribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
<img th:src="${(comment.user.image != null && !#strings.isEmpty(comment.user.image)) ? comment.user.image : '/images/default-user.png'}" th:alt="${comment.user.nameSurname}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This effectively checks whether string is empty or not which was exactly the case with our back-end. Большое спасибо, удачи.

Comment: I'm wondering why is `@{...}` syntax not used for link in this answer? Is `@{...}` syntax added only recently? Or does it not work with such conditional expressions?

Comment: Overall you can use `@{...}` syntax as well. It's almost the same as `${...}` beside the fact that it enriches value with things like app context URL, etc

Answer (score 1):

try.. change `&&` to `AND`

```
<img th:src="${(comment.user.image != null && !#strings.isEmpty(comment.user.image)) ? comment.user.image : '/images/default-user.png'}" th:alt="${comment.user.nameSurname}"/>
```

to

```
<img th:src="${(comment.user.image != null AND !#strings.isEmpty(comment.user.image)) ? comment.user.image : '/images/default-user.png'}" th:alt="${comment.user.nameSurname}"/>
```